# Get right data from dict inside list

Tags: python, data-structures, data-dictionary

I'm trying to get a video URL from tweet, `A` was taken from tweepy. Because twitter doesn't tell which one is the highest quality video I assume that I have to compare highest 'bitrate' and store the 'url' that corresponds with it. This is what I have.

Please bear with me, I'm new to this.

```
A = [{'content_type': 'application/x-mpegURL', 'url': 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/758995712280412672/pu/pl/X_6gAm0z8TBBbEAR.m3u8'},
    {'bitrate': 832000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/758995754280412672/pu/vid/360x640/6nxKFKpdku-qAl__.mp4'},
    {'content_type': 'application/dash+xml', 'url': 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/758995715280412672/pu/pl/X_6gAm0z8TBBbEAR.mpd'},
    {'bitrate': 320000, 'content_type': 'video/mp4', 'url': 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/758995715280412672/pu/vid/180x320/VqRF6IcnmsLxZIil.mp4'}]


for i, val in enumerate(A):
    if 'bitrate' in A[i]:
        print(A[i]['bitrate'], A[i]['url'])
```

This code produces

```
832000 https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/758996713280412672/pu/vid/360x640/6nxKFKpdku-qAl__.mp4
320000 https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/758997716280412672/pu/vid/180x320/VqRF6IcnmsLxZIil.mp4
```

How do I store the ['url'] that corresponds with highest ['bitrate'] into a variable?

Comment: So what is your question here?

Comment: max(A, key=lambda x:x['bitrate'])?

Comment: @IronFist Sorry I should make it clear, how do I store the ['url'] that corresponds with highest ['bitrate'] into a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get dictionary (or url) with the highest bitrate:

This compares the items of the list of dictionaries using `bitrate` key and returns dictionary with the highest `bitrate`.

```
max(A, key=lambda x:x['bitrate'])['url']
```

**EDIT:** According to your comment above, you can assign the url to variable of course.

```
variable = max(A, key=lambda x:x['bitrate'])['url']
```

**EDIT1:** According to your coment below - you believe right, you have to exclude such dictionaries from the list.

This excludes dictionaries without 'bitrate' key:

```
[d for d in A if d.has_key('bitrate')]
```

So you have to switch A to the line above so the result would be:

```
variable = max([d for d in A if d.has_key('bitrate')],key=lambda x:x['bitrate'])
```

Comment: This gives me error `KeyError: 'bitrate'`, I believe because not all dictionaries has 'bitrate'? Is there anyway to only compare the dictionaries that have 'bitrate'?

Comment: @YogaYudistira I've updated my answer. Please check it and if you satisfied mark it solved.